# android: Problem using schedule to call an animation

Tags: android, animation, schedule

When my app loads I have it animate a screen in. In the onAnimationEnd I call schedule to have it call a function 2 seconds later that will call an animation to animate the view out again. Currently it animates in, but the scheduler never seems to call the animate out. If I click home, then go back to the app it immediately calls the animate out. Why would, if the schedule is working, the app wait until it loses focus then gets focus back to actually trigger the function the schedule is supposed to call. Here's the code:

These are defined in the onCreate:

```
slideTopIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_top_in);
slideTopIn.setAnimationListener(slideTopInListener);
slideTopOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_top_out);
slideTopOut.setAnimationListener(slideTopOutListener);

freeAlertMsg.startAnimation(slideTopIn);
```

These are defined outside the onCreate within the activity class:

```
private AnimationListener slideTopInListener = new AnimationListener(){
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
        alertTimer.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { hideFreeAlert(); }
        }, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    };
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim){
        freeAlertMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    };
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim){

    };
};

private AnimationListener slideTopOutListener = new AnimationListener(){
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim){
        mainScreen.removeView(freeAlert);
    };
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim){
        Log.d("Animation Listener","slideTopOutListener");
    };
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim){

    };
};

private void hideFreeAlert(){
    freeAlertMsg.startAnimation(slideTopOut);
}
```

So basically it executes the startAnimation(slideTopIn). Then nothing happens. If i click home, then go back to the app, the startAnimation(slideTopOut) immediately executes. I'm guessing the schedule actually runs but never triggers the animation for some reason.

Comment: I'd get rid of the timer to see its affect and narrow down the problem.

Comment: I just did that. If I remove the time and just call the hideFreeAlert() right in the onAnimationEnd for the slideTopInListener it slides in then slides right out, as expected. So the problem is definitely in the scheduler some how.

Comment: switched my approach and followed this example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857101/schedule-task-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Just call `postDelayed()` on any `View`.